# URL warning in Django template, being asked to add semicolon in the url link object

Tags: django

I have an HTML link, upon clicking it will direct me to the respective link

```
<div onclick="location.href='{% url 'newscountry' 'Kuwait' %}'">
      Kuwait
    </div>
```

But I am being warned to add `;` in the above link (as `{% url 'newscountry'; 'Kuwait' %}'`)as per the attached image.

urls.py as below,

```
   path('country/<str:country>/',NewsCountryView.as_view(),name='newscountry'),
```

views.py

```
class NewsCountryView(ListView):
    model = News
    template_name = 'newsfront/index.html' # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'news'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 16
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        country=self.kwargs.get('country')
        return News.objects.filter(country=country)
```

[image]

Comment: I think that might be because you have single quotes inside single quotes, can you try escaping the outer pair?

Comment: I will try,however, I am getting results as planned. seems like negligible error

Comment: Why do you use `onclick` for that? Just use anchor tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install the [Django extension for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=batisteo.vscode-django) and it will perish.